# Woocommerce remove admin order item item meta

Tags: woocommerce

Im adding a custom item meta to every item with woocommerce_add_order_item_meta action.
I dont need to show this custom meta in the Order Detail, because it's an arry stringy that im using to print a pdf.

How can i remove this meta custom item? Is there some action to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I understand its a bit old question but I am answering for some other users who will have same issue in future.

If you want your order item meta to not display in admin order details page than you should append underscore (_) at the start of your meta name.

Example:

`_custom_order_meta`

Answer (score 2):

The underscore trick no longer works. In Woo 3.x there is a hidden meta array:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 
 array($this, 'hidden_order_itemmeta'), 50);

function hidden_order_itemmeta($args) {
  $args[] = 'my_hidden_meta';
  return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to keep it in order to print the PDF. If you override the `order-details.php` template you can possibly change:

```
$item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'], $_product );
```

to

```
$array = $item['item_meta'];
if( isset( $array['your_pdf_array_key'] ) ){ unset( $array['your_pdf_array_key'] ); }
$item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $array, $_product );
```

**EDIT**

The `wc_add_order_item_meta()` function has 4 parameters as seen in the code:

```
function wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false ) {
    return add_metadata( 'order_item', $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
}
```

If you choose a `$meta_key` with a preceding underscore, the meta will be automatically hidden from view on the checkout/order-received page, the My Order's list of the My account area, as well as in the admin's order overview page.

Therefore, I would suggest making your `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` callback function look something like the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', '25979024_add_order_item_meta', 10, 3 );

function 25979024_add_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_pdf_something', 'hide this stuff' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'hidden_order_itemmeta' );
function hidden_order_itemmeta( $args ) {
  $args[] = 'hideme1';
  $args[] = 'hideme2';
  $args[] = 'hideme3';
  return $args;
}
```